# Node-RED/javascript: convert multi line string to single line string - strg.replace does not work

Tags: javascript, string, base64, node-red

I am working in Node-RED and want to change a multi line string into a single line string. (the string is a base64 encoded image uploaded from another service) strg.replace does not work...

Comment: Hi - can you provide an example of the input you have and the output you want? What were you trying to do with .replace?

Comment: I've got a base64 encoded image (a string in multiple lines) and need it in one single line

Comment: Can you add a code snippet what you have already tried?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot replace all with `string.replace(string)`, instead you need to use another method such as `str.replace(/\n/g, "");` or `str.split("\n").join("")`.

`String.replace(String)` replaces the first occurrence of a character, while `str.replace(/regex/g)` will replace all and `str.split("\n")` will split the string into a newline separated array and join it back together with `.join("")`

Comment: Does your string have newlines (`\n`) or carriage return newlines (`\r\n`)? You may have to `str.split("\r\n").join("")`

Answer (score 0):

I'm 99.5% sure the latest version of the [node-red-node-base64](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-node-base64) should handle converting to and from buffers and handle input strings with or without newline chars.

If this is the case, you can convert both ways as the string output should be single line.

It's not pretty but it should work.

[EDIT]
Yep 100% sure it got [fixed](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-nodes/commit/8b53d09ad329df2f78e95514db4cc135600232f6)